# Градиент для текста

Tags: css

есть текст у которого цвет градиентным, в браузере он работает прекрасно, но когда открываешь на телефоне, то его нет. Как решить эту проблему?

Добавил вот этот код:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(269.19deg, #003EDD -19.84%, #09B7CF 61.69%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(269.19deg, #003EDD -19.84%, #09B7CF 61.69%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(269.19deg, #003EDD -19.84%, #09B7CF 61.69%);
background: linear-gradient(269.19deg, #003EDD -19.84%, #09B7CF 61.69%);
background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, там сказано, что поддерживается...

Answer (score 0):

Это можно проверить где угодно

Проверил на древнем планшете:https://ibb.co/Z86CxHz

Проверил на смарте:https://ibb.co/khr6Qnx

```css
.text {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  fill: url(#lg);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-10 -100 1200 200">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="lg">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:50%" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(5,200,0);stop-opacity:50%" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text font-size="40px" class="text">
    Это текст который поддерживается везде
  </text>
</svg>
```