# Заголовок, залитый изображением

Tags: html, css, css3, background

Как залить заголовок изображением?

Нужен такой эффект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фоновая картинка эта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.cover {height: 100vh;  width: 100%;  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);}

.title {color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);  font-weight: 900;  font-size: 25vw;  line-height: 90vh;  word-wrap: break-word;  text-align: center;  text-transform: uppercase;  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/phhrT.jpg");}
```

```html
<div class="cover"><div class="title">Горох</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить свойство `background-clip: text;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cover {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)), url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/phhrT.jpg");
}

.title {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/phhrT.jpg");
  filter: brightness(1.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 25vw;
  line-height: 90vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div class="title">Горох</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Говорят, что траблы на мобильных с `background-clip: text;` - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1095496/265406

Comment: про телефоны, прошивки и кривизну рук первооткрывателей коронавируса - согласен. Но, использование префикса, при поддержке всех браузеров, наводит на мысль о том, что про свойство подзабыли))